# Adding handlebars code to all questions in Amazon QnA bot

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I'm trying to add an automatic counter to our QnA bot on AWS. We'd like users to be allowed 7 questions, and at that point return a message that they've reached their limit.

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-ai-qna-bot/blob/master/lambda/proxy-es/lib/HANDLEBARS_README.md#available-variables-handlebars-context

Has instructions for adding handlebars code that probably could do what I need; something like:

```
{{#ifCond UserInfo.InteractionCount  '>' 6}}
  You have asked {{UserInfo.InteractionCount}} questions.
{{/ifCond}}
```

but I don't think copying-and-pasting this code into each and every question in the bot is the way to do it. Where would I apply this globally? Lambda seems like the obvious answer, but add it where? Also none of the Lambda code I see looks anything like the handlebars code examples. (Plus I don't need a steep learning curve, I just want to add this one function!)

Comment: Yes, you will have to write this function yourself in Lambda, either in NodeJS or Python. You'll also want to use a sessionAttribute to keep a persistent counter. You should try to add it to your Lambda code yourself and if you run into trouble, then share your code and we can help explain how to fix it up.

Comment: I honestly have no idea how to add handlebars code into a Lambda function. Meanwhile I'm trying something like this:

`const handlebars = require('handlebars');

handlebars.registerHelper("math", function(lvalue, operator, rvalue, options) {
    lvalue = parseFloat(lvalue);
    rvalue = parseFloat(rvalue);
        
    return {
        "+": lvalue + rvalue,
        "-": lvalue - rvalue,
        "*": lvalue * rvalue,
        "/": lvalue / rvalue,
        "%": lvalue % rvalue
    }[operator];
});`

Which throws a "handlebars is undefined" error. How to include code?